# Overriding a text file in a given line without creating a new file

Tags: java, overwrite, randomaccessfile

Without creating a new file and without using `RandomAccessFile` is this possible?

I have a .txt, where the content is as follows:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

I want to change the third line by YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY, so:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Comment: I'd guess not.  If I were you I'd look into why the random access file is failing and see if I could fix it.  What you are asking for is kind of the definition of random access...

Comment: forget RandomAccessFile, no is a way

Comment: You could read the file contents into memory, and replace the third line, the write *over* the file.

Comment: cricket_007, how can I do it?